# Equation in laravel where condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table **Item** with the following fields(latitude,longitude) and I have a function which has as parameters (lat, lon, radius)

then I want to retrieve data which accept the equation (|lon-longitude|/|lat-latitude|)<= radius

I am using laravel 5.4 like the following:

```
public function calc($lon, $lat, $radius){
    $result = Item::where()->get();
}
```

Any help how will the where condition be to do this equation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using the whereRaw

```
public function calc($lon, $lat, $radius){
    $result = Item::whereRaw("abs($lon-longitude)/abs($lat-latitude) <= $radius")->get();
}
```